# Hibernate getParameterValue() not working for collections

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a function like the following in a JPA Helper class:

```java
 public static Query copyQueryParameters(Query queryFrom, Query queryTo) {
    for (Parameter<?> param : queryFrom.getParameters()) {
        queryTo.setParameter(param.getName(), 
        queryFrom.getParameterValue(param));
    }
    return queryTo;
 }
```

which used to work well before I upgrade to Hibernate 5+.
Now, every time I try to find a parameter which is a collection or array it throws an `IllegalArgumentException` telling the value was not found. It does work for all non-collection parameters.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown parameter name : _status
```

`_status` in this case is a `List` of `enum`. But it doesn't work with any other kind of multi-valued params such as arrays or maps.

I have been using this to copy params from one query to another in order to make it possible to make a `select count...` without having to re-set all the query params.

Anyone else is facing this problem?

Comment: same problem . Did you get the solution ?

Comment: No, I didn't. Sorry.

Comment: hi anyone has the solution for above?